# Problem using HttpServletRequest authenticate() within JSF 2.0 preRenderView listener

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to use the authenticate() in a preRenderView listener method, in order to trigger authentication conditionally, depending on view parameters in the page. I tried adding a simple method:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class PermissionBean implements java.io.Serializable {
public void preRender() {
System.out.println("IN PRERENDER");

HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
try {
    request.authenticate(response);
} catch (Exception e) { // may throw ServletException or IOException
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

The authenticate method itself doesn't throw an exception, it triggers the redirect to Login.xhtml as expected. However, I'm getting in my server log, I get this exception:

```
enter code here

INFO: IN PRERENDER
FINEST: GET /Login.xhtml previous[3]
INFO: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at     com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:126)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2508)
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2129)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2077)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:286)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:244)
at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:670)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:108)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
```

So my request is not redirected to Login.xhtml.

My question is - is this something that should work within a JSF managed bean, or is it only legal outside of JSF request lifecycle? I tried calling authenticate() from a WebFilter, and it works as exptected.

Thanks,
Ellen

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell JSF to not render the response which it was initially asked to do, whenever the request has been redirected. You can do that by checking if [`HttpServletRequest#authenticate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#authenticate%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) returns `false` and then invoke [`FacesContext#responseComplete()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete%28%29) accordingly.

```
if (!request.authenticate(response)) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that I didn't test this  correctly - I just realized that I forgot to remove the ServletFilter I had created, so it was the ServletFilter that was authenticating, not my listener method.  

When I removed the ServletFilter, the call to responseComplete() fails because the current FacesContext is null, after the call to authenticate.  
I'm not sure the protocol for this - should I open a new question?